# How to use spinner to store values to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-spinner

I am creating a Classified application, I am stuck at Post Activity, where the user needs to select the Category to post their products. Below is the rough sketch for Post Activity.

[image]

Firebase Database Structure :

[image]

How to let the user select the Category from the Category list and based on that Category the item/products needs to be saved under that Structure.

For example : If the user needs to post an Advertisement for Audi, he will select "Cars" from the spinner list and that info(image,price,name) should be saved under "Cars" structure in the Firebase Database. Any help would be appreciated, I need to know the logic behind this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get spinner text like this.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

After you got selected text you can set DatabaseReference location.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("All Categories").child(text);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now! :)